# Spring controller not returning value when not using ResponseEntity

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have a controller like so,

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/sample")
    public ResponseEntity<> search() throws Exception{
        return new ResponseEntity("Hello World",OK);
    }
```

This works fine, but when I dont use ResponseEntity for returning the result but return the String instead, it does not work,

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/sample")
public String search() throws Exception{
    return "Hello Worls";
    }
```

This does not work and I get a 404! Any help greatly appreciated

Comment: how are you accessing this endpoint?

Comment: Guess because there is no view with the name `"Hello Worls"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ReponseBody` annotation:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/sample")
public @ResponseBody String search() throws Exception{
    return "Hello Worls";
}
```